# onChange not sending state to Api.create()

Tags: javascript, api

I am new to React js and Api. The dropdown onChange state from Header.js (which is inserted from another component) is not sending to getWOT(). Only the initial state value: defaultMonth can trigger the Api.create(). I am trying to debug using the console.log in getWOT(). Seems like having issue on the componentDidMount or the getWOT(). Please guide me on the mistake if have any. Thanks in advance.

```
import _ from "lodash";
import { React, Component } from "react";
import { CircularProgressbarWithChildren, buildStyles } from "react-circular-progressbar";
import Api from "./AllServices";
import "react-circular-progressbar/dist/styles.css";
import "./App.css";
import Header from './Header';

const d = new Date();
const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

const defaultMonth = months[d.getMonth()];
const formatMonth = value => {
var d = new Date(`${value} 01 2022`).toLocaleDateString(`en`, { month: `2-digit` });

return d;
};

class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
     isLoading: false,
     allWOT: [],
     value: defaultMonth,
     selectedMonth: formatMonth(defaultMonth),
  };
  this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);

}

onChange(event) {
  this.setState({ value: event.value, selectedMonth: formatMonth(event.value) });
}


componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({ isLoading: true})
  this.getWOT();
}

 getWOT() {
  console.log(this.state.selectedMonth);      '''selectedMonth is update here when dropdown value not changing'''
  Api.create().getWOT(this.state.selectedMonth).then(res => {
     if (res.ok) {
        if (res.data) {
           const data = _(res.data.Result)
              .groupBy('PRDLine')
              .map((value, key) => (
                 {
                    PRDLine: key,
                    Qty: _.sumBy(value, "Qty"),
                    FGOutQty: _.sumBy(value, "FGOutQty"),
                    FGRejQty: _.sumBy(value, "FGRejQty"),
                    DownMinutes: _.sumBy(value, "DownMinutes"),
                    Duration: _.sumBy(value.map((item) => {
                       const d1 = new Date(item.FinishDateTime);
                       const d2 = new Date(item.ProcessDateTime);
                       return parseInt((Math.abs(Math.round(d1.getTime() - d2.getTime()) / 60000)))
                    }))
                 }
              ))
              .value();

           this.setState({
              allWOT: data,
              isLoading: false, 
           });
        }
        else {
           window.alert(res.problem)
        }

     }
  })
 }


render() {
  console.log(this.state.selectedMonth);       '''selectedMonth is update here when dropdown value changes'''
  
  

  const Total_target = _.sumBy(this.state.allWOT, x => x.Qty);
  const Total_output = _.sumBy(this.state.allWOT, x => x.FGOutQty);
  const Total_percentage = ((Total_output) / (Total_target) * 100).toFixed(1);

  const renderusers = _.map(this.state.allWOT, (value) => (

     <div className="line-grids" id="grid2">
        <div className="line-title" id="Line2">Line {value.PRDLine[1]}</div>
        <div className="line-target" id="line2-target">TARGET Output: {value.Qty} pcs</div>
        <div className="line-circle" id="grid2-circle">
           <CircularProgressbarWithChildren value={((value.FGOutQty) / (value.Qty) * 100).toFixed(1)} strokeWidth="16" styles={buildStyles({ strokeLinecap: 'butt', pathColor: '#8bc34a' })}>
              <div>{value.FGOutQty} pcs</div>
              <div>{((value.FGOutQty) / (value.Qty) * 100).toFixed(1)} %</div>
           </CircularProgressbarWithChildren>
        </div>

        <div className="line-bars">
           <div className="bar-title">Downtime</div>
           <div className="container">
              <div className="progress" style={{ width: ((value.DownMinutes) / (value.Duration) * 100).toFixed(1) + '%'}}>{((value.DownMinutes) / (value.Duration) * 100).toFixed(1)}%</div>
           </div>
        </div>

        <div className="line-bars">
           <div className="bar-title">No Schedule</div>
           <div className="container">
              <div className="progress" style={{ width: 90 + '%'}}>{90}</div>
           </div>
        </div>

        <div className="line-bars">
           <div className="bar-title">Total Reject</div>
           <div className="container">
              <div className="progress" style={{ width: ((value.FGRejQty) / (value.Qty) * 100).toFixed(1) + '%' }}>{((value.FGRejQty) / (value.Qty) * 100).toFixed(1)}%</div>
           </div>
        </div>

     </div>

  ));



  return (
     


     this.state.isLoading ?
        <h3 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>loading...</h3>
        :

        <div>
           <Header value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange}/>
           

           <div className="grid-container">
              <div className="main-grid">
                 <div className="prod-title">Production Output</div>
                 <div className="prod-target">TARGET Output: {Total_target} pcs</div>
                 <div className="prod-circle">
                    <CircularProgressbarWithChildren value={Total_percentage} strokeWidth="16" styles={buildStyles({ strokeLinecap: 'butt', pathColor: '#673ab7' })}>
                       <div>{Total_output} pcs</div>
                       <div>{Total_percentage} %</div>
                    </CircularProgressbarWithChildren>
                 </div>
              </div>

              {renderusers}

           </div>


        </div>
  );
 }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, now I got it. I recall getWOT() function in onChange() function.

Like this,

```
 onChange(event) {
  this.setState({value: event.value, selectedMonth: formatMonth(event.value)}, ()=> {this.getWOT()});
```

Now, it's working fine. Thank you.